# Cron Expression for Hour:Minute to Hour:Minute

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am using Cron Expressions with Quartz.NET, and having a problem generating the cron expression for a Start `Hour:Minute` and End `Hour:Minute`

If I have a Job I want to run every 5 minutes from `10:20 AM` to `11:25 AM` what should be the correct cron expression,

At the moment I have this: `0 20-25/5 10-11 1/1 * ? *`

But this only runs at `10:20, 10:25, 11:20 and 11:25`

```
1   Monday, June 6, 2016 11:20 AM
2   Monday, June 6, 2016 11:25 AM
3   Tuesday, June 7, 2016 10:20 AM
4   Tuesday, June 7, 2016 10:25 AM
5   Tuesday, June 7, 2016 11:20 AM
6   Tuesday, June 7, 2016 11:25 AM
7   Wednesday, June 8, 2016 10:20 AM
8   Wednesday, June 8, 2016 10:25 AM
9   Wednesday, June 8, 2016 11:20 AM
10  Wednesday, June 8, 2016 11:25 AM
```

But what it should do is run from `10:20 AM till 11:25 AM`, every five minutes

```
10:20, 10:25, 10:30, 10:35, 10:40 ....... 11:20, 11:25
```

Answer (score 1):

Quartz does exactly what you Cron expression is saying, ie every 5 minutes between minutes 20 and 25 included for hours 10 and 11. And there is no way to achieve this with one Cron expression only...

This is usually done using a trigger with daily time interval schedule (`TriggerBuilder.Create().WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(...)`) with 10:20 as daily start time, 11:25 as daily end time and with a 5 minutes interval.

If your trigger HAD TO be fired only on minutes 0 or 5, also add to the trigger a misfire instruction policy to avoid time shifting in case of recovery (See https://dzone.com/articles/quartz-scheduler-misfire)

Comment: so this is not possible to do with a Cron Expression?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't with one cron expression but you can use two (which is pretty shitty IMO but if you really want too ... ^^). With two cron expressions, define the first like that `0 20/5 10 1/1 * ? *` and the second one like this `0 0-25/5 11 1/1 * ? *`

Comment: so that will be basically created 2 triggers for the Job to be executed, yes?

Comment: If you want to use the solution with two cron, yes exactly. You will have to schedule two *distinct* triggers each one with one of the cron expression above