# Cron expression to run a program between 2 hours and 15 minutes every 2 minutes

Tags: cron

I need to execute a program between 08:15 and 07:15 (next day) every 2 minutes. It shouldn't run between 7:15 and 8:15.

With this expression `0 0/2 0-7,8-23 * * ?`, the program runs between 08:00 and 07:00 (next day) every 2 minutes, however I don't know how to make it stop/start at the minute 15.

I've found in Stackoverflow similar questions, but the execution expressions don't include the hour interval, this is what makes it more tricky.

I also found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656211/cron-expression-for-hourminute-to-hourminute), that is similar. They say it's not possible, but it is 7 years old, I don't know if maybe nowdays there is a solution.

Ideas?